# The program executes a line of code multiple times

Tags: android, socket.io

I try write a messenger with 'socket.io'.
and write this.

```
//Socket.
private Socket socket;
{
    try {
        socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.3:8001");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Tools.
Handler handlerServerMakeMeOnline;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a_room_list);

    handlerServerMakeMeOnline = new Handler();
    socket.connect();
    socket.on("serverMakeMeOnline", serverMakeMeOnlineListener);
}



private Emitter.Listener serverMakeMeOnlineListener = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        handlerServerMakeMeOnline.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(RoomListA.this, "Online", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    socket.emit("makeMeOffline", userCode);
    socket.disconnect();
    socket.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

But I have a strange problem.
When I open the program for the first time, everything is working properly.
But when I close app and open it again, the `Toast` inside `serverMakeMeOnlineListener` is called twice, and if I close and open app again `Toast` is called thrice etc

Comment: try to add this during onDestroy: socket.off("makeMeOffline", handlerServerMakeMeOnline); After the socket.disconnect();

Comment: also add serverMakeMeOnlineListener =null in onDestroy()

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? I mean actually debugging, checking the memory addresses if needed and so on... The is a quite simple issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is happening because you are not removing the `Emitter.Listener` during `onDestroy`
This way, everytime you open your app, you are adding a new `Emitter.Listener` causing the `Toast` to be displayed more than once.

So, try this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    socket.disconnect();
    socket.off("makeMeOffline", handlerServerMakeMeOnline);
    socket.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Let me know if that works.. If not, I'll delete this answer